when i want to run node-red using command prompt, when i enter the ip address on my browser, it does not open the dashboard, what could be the problem
i installed node-red with command prompt and when i want to open it after typing node-red on command prompt, it gives the the ip adress and all but when i paste the ip address on my browser, it does not open the node-red dashboard
i tried redoing it to no avail, even removed the last slash on the ip address and it still did not work, dashboard did not open
during installation, using the install -g --unsafe-perm node-red command it gives a line that says 'added 303 packages in 41s, 46 packages are looking for funding, run npm fund for details'
when i run npm fund command it returns the message 'USER'

The funding information is not related to what you are trying to do.

Also to be clear, the Node-RED dashboard is a specific package that can be installed in Node-RED, are you sure you do not mean the Node-RED editor, which is where you develop/edit flows?

The log on start up assumes you are running Node-RED on the same machine as the browser you are using to access the Node-RED Editor so suggests accessing on http://127.0.0.1:/1880
If you are trying to access it from a different machine then you need to replace the 127.0.0.1 (loopback) IP address with the IP address of the machine you are running Node-RED on.
Assuming you installed Node-RED on a Linux machine and SSH'd into it then you should be able to use the same hostname or IP address as you used with SSH
Otherwise you can open a new terminal on the machine you installed Node-RED on and run the following command
ip a

This will list all the IP addresses the machine has (it will list 127.0.0.1 but you can ignore that as it is only accessible from the same machine). You probably want to look for the IP address associated with either eth0 or wlan0

accessing it on http://127.0.0.1:1880 is not working either. im running it on the same machine (windows)

Then are you leaving the terminal you are running node-red in open? You will only be able to access the editor while it is running

Just checking, after installing you did run node-red to actually start the application? Node-RED does not run automatically and will need to be started when ever you want to use it. (There are ways to make it run as a Windows service, but these are additional steps)
